# Primefaces BlockUI for any click action on the page

Tags: primefaces, blockui

Is there a way to give component types to trigger instead of component id as follows,

```
<p:blockUI block="myPanel" trigger="Button, HyperLink" />
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem and share with one who has the same problem.

Primeface Part:

```
<p:blockUI widgetVar="blockUi" block="wholeBody" ></p:blockUI>
```

Note that: widgetVar must be defined (not Id) for operating the component in JavaScript

JavaScript Part:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function() {
            PF('blockUi').show();
        });

        $(document).on('pfAjaxComplete', function() {
            PF('blockUi').hide();
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

For more detail about what widgetVar and PF() are, please read the reference.

Reference: http://blog.hatemalimam.com/intro-to-primefaces-widgetvar/